# Why doesn't my audio play in the background?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, mmppf

I'm using this page to keep my audio playing across pages.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mmppf="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="player" AutoPlay="True" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" />
        <Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is how my App Manifest looks.
[image]

But once I background my app, the audio stops playing.
From what I can see, everything [mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx) is present in my app

(the `MediaPlayer` element should take care of the `SystemMediaTransportControls`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you're referring to is only applicable to Windows Store apps, not Windows Phone 8.1.

For Windows Phone 8.1, things seem more complicated, as you have to implement a background task, as explained here: [Overview: Background audio (Windows Phone Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx)

Comment: Isn't a universal app a Store app? Do you know how I'd get the `MediaPlayer` XAML element from my app in the background task?

Comment: A universal app is an app that can be deployed on both Windows and Windows Phone, but that doesn't mean it can use features that do not exist (or work differently) on each platform.

Comment: I would suggest you start from this example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how I'd get a XAML element from my background task (the MediaPlayer element which needs to be in the visual tree)

Comment: A background task accesses the MediaPlayer using BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current. This is all explained in the links I provided. The architecture to play background audio in Windows Phone 8.1 is entierly different that Windows 8 or previous versions of Windows Phone...

Comment: After following that example the audio plays in the background. Thanks!